# Which column classes should be used in Bootstrap to create more resposive Webpage

Tags: bootstrap-grid

BootStrap allows four types of classes for column/Grid System.

```html
.xs // for mobiles
.sm // for tablest
.md // for laptops and normal desktops
.lg // for larger desktop
```

Suppose i want to create a webpage/website which should be more resposive (definitely it must be) for all type of media.  from  mobiles to larger desktop. Can i use classes in this formate. 
**Note**: In this example i am going to create left side column.

```html
<div class="left-col col-xs-12 , col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
```

In above Example , i used col-xs-12 so that when screen is smaller then its width should be 100% , similarly col-sm-12 . and i used col-md-3 so that if screen size is more than 700px(approx) , the column's width should be 25% and similarly with col-lg-3.
So again i repeat my Question that should i combined all four classes to make more responsive and dynamic webpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be enough to achieve your goal

```
<div class="left-col col-sm-12 col-md-3">
```

It will use the full width when the device is a tablet or below. And it will use 1/4 of the width when its a laptop or larger desktop pc.